# Setting a delegate in Android

Tags: java, android, delegates

I need to accomplish the following:

```
AdBuddiz.RewardedVideo.setDelegate(delegate);
```

And the documentation for this SDK says "The delegate must implement the following interface":

```
interface AdBuddizRewardedVideoDelegate {
  void didComplete();    // user fully watched the video, give the reward here 

  // optional
  void didFetch();       // a video is ready to be displayed
  void didFail(AdBuddizRewardedVideoError error); // SDK was unable to fetch or show a video
  void didNotComplete(); // an error happened during video playback
}
```

I am familiar with delegation in iOS, however I am unfamiliar how this works in Java / Android. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Add this to your Activity: `implements AdBuddizRewardedVideoDelegate`, in order to get access to the interface methods

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the classes you are using, but it looks like you just have to implement this interface. You could do this using an anonymous class. Something like

```
myRewardVideo.setDelegate(new AdBuddizRewardedVideoDelegate() {

    @Override
    public void didComplete() {
        // write what you want to happen here.
    }

    @Override
    public void didFetch() {
        // write what you want to happen here.
    }

    @Override
    public void didFail(AdBuddizRewardedVideoError error) {
        // write what you want to happen here.
    }

    @Override
    public void didNotComplete() {
        // write what you want to happen here.
    }
});
```

The last 3 methods are optional, so if you do not want anything to happen in those cases, you can just get rid of those methods.